# Behavior of element.offsetHeight affectation and doctype

Tags: javascript, css, doctype

Given the code below:

- HTML:

  ```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
             "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

  <html>
      <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          <title>Test</title>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body onload="init()">
      <div id="test" style="height:200px;border:2px solid black">A box</div>
      <button id="test-button">Reduce</button>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```
- Javascript:

  ```
  // script.js
  function reduce() {
      var div = document.getElementById("test");
      console.log(div.offsetHeight);
      div.style.height="<VALUE>"; // test value
      console.log(div.offsetHeight);
  }

  function init() {
      document.getElementById("test-button").onclick = reduce;
  }
  ```

I realised the following behavior:

- if `<VALUE>` is given with an explicit unit (tested with `px`), everything is OK (`offsetHeight` will be updated and the element will be modifed)
- if  is given without an unit (`100` for example):

  - without a doctype, it will works (idem)
  - with a given doctype (tested with `<!DOCTYPE html>`), it **won't work** (no updating nor error log in the browser console)

Tested with Firefox 69.0. Is there some documentation explaining this behavior? I know that no doctype means "quirk mode", but I'm looking for a source more accurate.

Comment: A note on your actual HTML: your doctype suggests HTML5, so that meta should be `<meta charset="windows-1252">` (but really, you want `utf-8` unless you have _really_ good reasons not to present a unicode document). Also, there is no reason to include `type` in link and script tags because in HTML5 those are css and js by default. Also, don't use inline JS: put your script element at the bottom of the page, make it find your button (`document.querySelector('button')`) and then use `addEventListener` to add a click listener to that button. And really, don't set CSS through JS. Set a class.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, thanks and you're right. Actually I set up a MVCE just to expose the point (explicitness of the doctype). In order to avoid any distraction, I updated the question and put _on purpose_ an old doctype followed by W3C-validated HTML code and javascript of same age. I'm dealing with a quite old legacy codebase. Then, this sample is just meant to be viewed as an illustration of what happens when the doctype is specified or not.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, also I admit, it wasn't a "minimal" example.

Comment: okay, but that takes it in the opposite direction: if you write normal modern HTML5 code (which of course we all should) then you don't run into this problem, so this isn't a true "programming" question, but a quirks mode question: why does setting height without a unit work in quirks mode, but not in normal mode. The answer to the latter is "because it's wrong, and shouldn't work". So really this question is just "why does this ancient code, that no one in their right mind would use today, work?" and then really the counter-question is "... why? Are you working on a legacy code base?"

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, yes, the true question is the one which lies inside my last sentences: is the quirk mode behavior documented?

Comment: Probably worth updating your title and post body over, then. It's an interesting question, I didn't find anything on https://www.quirksmode.org or with some websearching, but you'll probably get more eyes on it as a spec question, rather than a code question.

Comment: This is called the [unitless length quirk](https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-unitless-length-quirk) in the Quirks Mode Standard

Comment: @Alohci, exactly what I was looking for. If you put it as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.